# How to read specific lines from list

Tags: python-3.x

I want to extract from 46th line to 1420th line from a list, not single characters in the lines. I tried `for loop`:

```
spec_lines = np.arange(45,1421)
for i in spec_lines:
    line = fp[i]
    i += 1
    data += line
print(data)
```

It returned single characters like (46th line as example)
`[' ', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', ' ', 'p', 'o', 'i', 'n', 't', 's', ' ', 'o', 'f', ' ', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'e', 'l',...`

However, if I do `p = fp[45]` it returned p as `11000 points of accel data`, this is what I expected to get.

Comment: You missed code where you assign `fp`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, Olvin, I'm still practicing how to ask, I wasn't sure if it would help to post a minimal, repeatable question, as mentioned in the question, the type of ```fp``` is a list.
I forgot to add ``data = []``.

Comment: Read how to write a [mcve].
Have fun and happy hacking :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
data="".join(your_list[45:1421])
```